# Migrating from Spring security oauth to spring security core 6.1.0 getting 'principalName cannot be empty' error

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I am working on migrating from spring security oauth to spring security core and I just changed our securityfilter chain that used to look like

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;

/** Security configuration for the application */
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

  @Override
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.csrf().disable().authorizeRequests().anyRequest().permitAll();
  }
}
```

but now i have changed it to look like this (essentially just getting rid of the deprecated stuff

```
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig {

  @Bean
  public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable).authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> auth.anyRequest().permitAll());
    return http.build();
  }
}
```

now whenever i run an integration test or make a request on our api I receive the error below coming from loadAuthorizedClient function in the *InMemoryOAuth2AuthorizedClientService* file from the spring security apache libraries

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: principalName cannot be empty
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.hasText(Assert.java:294)
```

not sure how to set this or even possibly disable it

Not even sure where to begin.  I tried setting a principal and it still comes up as null.  I tried writing another bean to overwrite the one from their library with something that has a test principalname, and a few other methods.  Most stack overflow suggestions ive seen on similar posts say to use a bunch of libraries that are all deprecated/non-existent in spring security core 6.  The released migration guide from spring security core is not helpful either.

Answer (score 0):

Can use @WithMockUser in IT.

or

create customMockUser

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@WithSecurityContext(factory = CustomUserSecurityContextFactory.class)
public @interface CustomMockUser {

    String username() default "user";

    String userId() default "";

    @AliasFor(annotation = WithSecurityContext.class)
    TestExecutionEvent setupBefore() default TestExecutionEvent.TEST_EXECUTION;
}
```

and

```
public class CustomUserSecurityContextFactory implements WithSecurityContextFactory<CustomMockUser> {

@Override
public SecurityContext createSecurityContext(CustomMockUser withUser) {
    JwtAuthenticationToken authentication = new JwtAuthenticationToken(Jwt.withTokenValue(UUID.randomUUID().toString())
                    .claim(KeycloakAuthToken.SESSION_ID_CLAIM, UUID.randomUUID().toString())
                    .claim(KeycloakAuthToken.USER_LOGIN_CLAIM, withUser.username())
                    .header("typ", "JWT")
                    .build());

    SecurityContext context = SecurityContextHolder.createEmptyContext();
    context.setAuthentication(authentication);
    return context;
}
}
```